# SAS error using prxmatch with DS2

Tags: regex, sas, sas-ds2

It appears to me that there is an error when using prxmatch with SAS DS2.  It is also possible my code is in error.  I want to know if this problem is because of my code or a compile error with SAS.

In the code below I match search terms in one data table with search text in another.

```
data master_table;
    input name $ search_text $;
    datalines;
Frank   allHere
John    Sales
Mary    Acctng
Joe     Findme
Sue     Hereiam
Jim     graccaa
;
run;

proc print data= master_table; run;

data search_term_table;
    infile datalines missover;
    input id $ search_term $;
datalines;
1   Here
2   Find
3   Acc
;
run;

proc ds2;
    data search_results (overwrite=yes);
    retain rc;
    dcl double rc c ;
    declare char(8) id N;
    declare char(11) name;
    declare char(1) c_options;
    declare char(20) search_term search_text;
    dcl package hash h(1, 'search_term_table');
    dcl package hiter hi('h');
        method init();
            rc = h.keys([id]);
            rc = h.data([id search_term]);
            rc = h.defineDone();
        end;
        method run();
            dcl double rc;
            set master_table;
            if _N_ = 1 then put 'ROW    ITEM';
            N = _N_;
            rc = hi.first();
            do while(rc=0);
                c_options = 'i';
                search_term = cats('/', search_term, '/', c_options);
                search_text = catx(' ', search_text);
                c = prxmatch(search_term, search_text);
                put N id 'prxmatch(' search_term ',' search_text '); ---> ' c;
                output;
                rc = hi.next();
            end;
        end;
    enddata;
run;
quit;
```

The results of the put statement are shown below.

In `ROW 3` `ITEM 1` a match is incorrectly found, because it is using the regex from the last item of the previous row, not the current one.

In `ROW 5` `ITEM 1` the situation is reversed.  A match is not found because, again, it is using the regex from the last item of the previous row.

```
ROW    ITEM
1        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , allHere              ); --->  4
1        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , allHere              ); --->  0
1        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , allHere              ); --->  0
2        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , Sales                ); --->  0
2        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , Sales                ); --->  0
2        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , Sales                ); --->  0
3        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , Acctng               ); --->  1
3        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , Acctng               ); --->  0
3        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , Acctng               ); --->  1
4        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , Findme               ); --->  0
4        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , Findme               ); --->  1
4        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , Findme               ); --->  0
5        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , Hereiam              ); --->  0
5        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , Hereiam              ); --->  0
5        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , Hereiam              ); --->  0
6        1        prxmatch( /Here/i              , graccaa              ); --->  3
6        2        prxmatch( /Find/i              , graccaa              ); --->  0
6        3        prxmatch( /Acc/i               , graccaa              ); --->  3
NOTE: Execution succeeded. 18 rows affected.
2752  quit;
```

Comment: What is this statement supposed to be doing `search_text = catx(' ', search_text);` ?

Comment: It doesn't do anything. It is just the remains of a different direction.  I doubt its presence is causing the problem I describe.

Comment: You can also open a track with SAS Tech Support at https://support.sas.com/ctx/supportform/createForm and it will likely get bumped to the actual developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `PRXMATCH` might be doing some weird compiled regex caching with an implicit `/o`. I can't figure out the rationale behind the observed output, even when considering some PRXMATCH pattern may have been compiled 'once'.

Unfortunately, DS2 does not like `CALL PRXDEBUG(1);` which might have shed some light.

From [PRXMATCH docs](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=lefunctionsref&docsetTarget=n0bj9p4401w3n9n1gmv6tfshit9m.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en)

> **Compiling a Perl Regular Expression**
>   If perl-regular-expression is a constant or if it uses the /o option, then the Perl regular expression is compiled once and each use of PRXMATCH reuses the compiled expression. If perl-regular-expression is not a constant and if it does not use the /o option, then the Perl regular expression is recompiled for each call to PRXMATCH.
>  
>   **Note:** The compile-once behavior occurs when you use PRXMATCH in a DATA step, in a WHERE clause, or in PROC SQL. For all other uses, the perl-regular-expression is recompiled for each call to PRXMATCH.

So the docs don't quite spell out what happens in DS2, but you know sometimes something special happens.

The best *fix* is to explicitly PRXPARSE the dynamic regex pattern to get an id that is used in PRXMATCH

```
            dcl int rx;
            rx = prxparse(search_term);
            c = prxmatch(rx, search_text);
```

This could be memory problematic because there is not a `PRXFREE` function and DS2 does not allow use of call routine `CALL PRXFREE(rx);`  To avoid the potential 'memory` problem create an array or hash of ids of prxparsed patterns that will be used and use the ids retrieved via search_term lookup.

Comment: Thanks,  I think your suggestion of making a hash of ids is the best solution.  One solution I also tried was to make the data set I am trying to parse be the hash, then reading through the data set of search terms.